# Kendo client template not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-template

```
columns: [{
    field: "FileName",
    title: "FileName",
    width: 150
    }, {     
    title: "Action",
    template:'<ahref="/DbBackup/Download?FileName=#=FileName#">Download</a>'
}],
```

My controller is

```
public ActionResult Download(String FileName) 
{
    .....
}
```

I have a grid containing two columns. First is `FileName` which displays .bak file and second is `Action` column whose data should be redirecting to `ActionResult Download()` in controller `DbBackup` with the corresponding filename as its parameter. It is redirecting to controller on click, but the controller isnot accepting the filename. The parameter of actionmethod i.e FileName is null

The url looks fine:    localhost:15536/DbBackup/Download/0123897_545.bak

Comment: Is file name not being sent from browser or controller is not receiving?

Comment: How does request URL in header looks?

Comment: If you fix the param like `?FileName=test` and get it on the action parameters, you'll be sure that the FileName isn't available on the grid.

Comment: It looks like controller is refusing to take the parameter
the url looks like this 
http://localhost:15536/Controller/Download/0123897_545.bak

Comment: Maybe try adding slash at the end `http://localhost:15536/Controller/Download/0123897_545.bak/`. and you might need to change routes to accept optional param `Filename`

Comment: Did it still doesnot work

Comment: Why does your controller in url is named "controller"? And why there is no param name "FileName" in url? It should look like this `localhost:15536/DbBackup/Download?FileName=0123897_545.bak`